# How to change selection Font Family of RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

How can I change `Font-Family` of selected Text in `RichEditBox` in `UWP`?

Comment: you want to change only selected text or whole text inside rich text box?

Comment: only selected text inside RichEditBox in UWP.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the font family of the selected text by using:

```
YourRichEditBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Name = "Segoe UI";
```

Replace "Segoe UI" with your font family name. Segoe UI is the default font family.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this may help

```
void Change_Family_Font(RichTextBox txt, FontFamily FF ,string SearchFor)
    {
        txt.HideSelection = false;
        int Pos = txt.Find(SearchFor, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
        if (Pos != -1){
            txt.SelectionStart = Pos;
            txt.SelectionLength = SearchFor.Length;
            txt.SelectionFont = new Font(FF, 14, FontStyle.Regular);
        }     
    }
```

Comment: code-only answers aren't useful for the community. Please look at [answer]

Comment: I am using RichEditBox in UWP. RichTextBox is WPF control.